# Linux ssh shell prompt

Tags: shell, ssh

While trying to type `~/Code`, I somehow got myself to some sort of ssh shell:

```
┌─[jpearson@cominor] - [~/code] - [Fri Aug 05, 06:08]
└─[$]> 
ssh> ^D
```

As you can see, ctrl+d exited me out of it, but I'm rather curious to know what I found, and how I got there.  Attempting to Google around got me nowhere.

I'm using zsh, but I don't know if that's relevant.  CentOS 5.

Answer (score 7):

You'll have accidentally typed `~C`, which is the default "drop to a shell" key sequence for SSH.  You can disable this behaviour by putting `-e none` on the command line, or `EscapeChar none` in your SSH config file.

Comment: You can also see the list of escape commands with `~?`.  openssh only processes the ~ character if it's the very first character on a new line (which it detects based on whether you just hit enter or not so really the escape character should be considered "enter~", not based on whether whatever program you're running has moved the cursor or not). Better to know what it is and how it works since it is useful for using `~.` to kill ssh when the network has stalled.